# Pattern Matching in MS Access: Is there an "or" operator?

Tags: regex, ms-access

I've tried searching online for the answer to this, but my Google-fu has failed me.

I have an Access database containing records represented by a string.  The first 3 characters of that string are a 3-digit representation of the 366-day calendar date on which the record was created (000-366...yes, leap days count).

I'm having trouble coming up with the correct pattern match to include in a query that matches a 3-digit substring that can be between 000 and 366, where you don't lose the significant figures.

I know the query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Field1 LIKE "^[0-2]## or 3[0-5]# or 36[0-6]*";
```

...but I can't find any resource that says, in MS Access, what the "or" operator is.  I tried "||" (double pipe) and "|" (single pipe), neither of which worked.

Is there an "or" operator that can be used with a MS Access pattern match?

Comment: jetsql supports regexes? that's news...

Comment: And what if that string begins with `0000`? Does that mean this is day 0?

Comment: There are no values with 4 significant figures, only 3.  So "000" is day 0, but "0000" is still day 0, but the fourth 0 is not part of the 3-digit value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pull the first three characters?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CInt(Left(Field1,3)) <= 366
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cint.php

Answer (score 2):

The [`LIKE` operator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx) in Access is pretty limited, and doesn't support most of the features more 'fully-fledged' regular expression engines provide.

Instead, use multiple conditions in your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Field1 LIKE "[0-2]##*" OR 
      Field1 LIKE "3[0-5]#*" OR 
      Field1 LIKE "36[0-6]*"
```

Another alternative is to simply extract the first 3 characters to a string, convert them to an integer and test to see if their value is within the acceptable range.

Comment: I figured this was one approach, but I was hoping for an "or" operator just because this isn't the only portion of the pattern match, and if I have extra clauses it makes the query longer and more confusing.